# How to pick/configure AWS GPU Instances to speed up TensorFlow.keras?

Tags: performance, tensorflow, keras, nvidia, tensorflow2.x

I have a LSTM tf.keras model with about 600MB of training data. It takes about 90 seconds for each training epoch. I have the latest version of tensorflow, which is v2.2. It runs on an AWS g3.4xlarge instance. This instance has the Tesla M60 GPU from Nvidia and has 8GB of RAM for the GPU.

I want to do hyperparameter tuning and so I need to speed up the execution. So I moved the model and data to an AWS p3.2xlarge instance which has a P100 GPU with 16GB of RAM. Then I found the training time for each epoch did not change at all.

So I switched to an even larger AWS instance, p3.8xlarge, which has 4 Tesla V100 GPUs and 64GB of RAM total. In the first run, it only used 1 GPU and yielded the same execution time for each epoch, about 90 seconds. So I found an article on tensorflow website on how to use all GPUs, https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu

So with all 4 GPUs running, the execution time for an epoch went from 90 seconds to 112 seconds! I used nvtop and nvidia-smi to monitor the GPU performance, as shown below.
[image]

[image]

What do I need to do to reduce the execution time?

Comment: Do the profiling and post the results. Tensorflow profiler will provide you with some hints. Do you observe kernel launch overhead? How you networks looks like? What are the parameters on LSTM? That can play a major role.

Comment: Can you post some examples of profiling? The LSTM has 50 cells with input_shape=(96,4). The rest of parameters are defaults.

Comment: Enable profiling on `tensorboard`, here's one example: https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/tensorboard_profiling_keras

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it try.

Answer (score 1):

The amount of time to run each epoch will obviously be the same until you don't change anything in the network. Just running it on a bigger GPU is not the answer here.

First of all if you can change your network to reduce the number of parameters then it will be great. So, reducing your model is obviously the first thing to make it run faster.

But, if that is not possible, here are two thing you can do:

1. Use tf.mixed_precision to run your model faster.

```
from tensorflow.keras.mixed_precision import experimental as mixed_precision
policy = mixed_precision.Policy('mixed_float16')
mixed_precision.set_policy(policy)
```

It offers significant computational speedup by performing operations in the half-precision format while storing minimal information in single-precision to retain as much information as possible in critical parts of the network.

2. Use XLA.

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.config.optimizer.set_jit(True)
```

Accelerated Linear Algebra, XLA is a domain-specific compiler for matrix operations. It can make your network faster without any changes in your source code.

Please try both of these. I have personally used mixed precision and it surely does reduce the network time.

Also, please next time don't jump to bigger instances as it is a waste of your money. Just try to reduce the number of parameters (i.e. network size) or use these two tricks. I'll update this answer if I find any new trick.

Comment: Also, if you are wondering why your network got slower on those 4-GPU instances, it was because data division and data consolidation for the computation gave you the slow speed as memory transfer was then involved.

Comment: Have you tried mixed_precision or XLA on GPU computation? I tried them individually and they actually slowed down the computation. I set the verbose=1 in the model.fit(). Each epoch takes a bit longer with them.